# Problem identifying correct driver for I/O expanders on embedded device

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, i2c, usrp

I'm using the embedded device(USRP N310) and I've been trying to figure out what drivers are associated with particular devices on the platform such as the I/O expanders, the TCA6408 and the TCA6424A. From the device, I go into /sys/bus/i2c/drivers directory and I'm able to see all the drivers associated with i2c. There is a driver listed, pca953x, that that lists the addresses of the I/O expander devices of interest. Furthermore, when I go into one of the subdirectories for one of the devices, 10-0020, which describes adapter number and the address of the device, there is symlink to the pca953x driver as shown here [image: Screen capture of driver symlink]

I believe this to be the driver associated with the I/O expander devices of interest but I would have expected the drivers to be different. Namely, I would have expected a driver named tca6408 for that particular chip and perhaps a different driver named tca6424 for the other chip. Is this the correct driver for these chips or am I misinterpreting what I'm seeing here?

Comment: pca953x seems to be the correct driver. If you look in the device ID table [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/gpio/gpio-pca953x.c#L1200) you can see it supports lots of different I2C I/O expander chips.